# Get value from string parameter of JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

In the following standard function you can put in multiple arguments for the second and third parameter.

```
var retval = window.showModalDialog(dialog, varArgIn, varOptions);
```

The varOptions parameter can be filled with:

```
'dialogHeight:580px;dialogWidth:700px;center=yes;scroll=no',
```

How do I get the only the value that's set at dialogHeight? So I can re-use only that value somewhere else.

Comment: I would do it with Regular Expressions...

Comment: Don't understand your problem. YOU fill the varOptions, don't you?
Just create new variable for each option and re-use them all you want.

Comment: HenrikPeinar Just an example, it's an existing function I'll overwrite.
algorhythm I tried, didn't get one to work.

Comment: Do you mean `var dialogHeight = 580; var options = 'dialogHeight:' + dialogHeight +'px;dialogWidth:700px;center=yes;scroll=no';`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple regular expression:

```
'dialogHeight:580px;dialogWidth:700px;center=yes;scroll=no'.match(/dialogHeight:\w+/)[0]; //dialogHeight:580px
```

In your case, probably you'll need: `varOptions.match(/dialogHeight:\w+/)[0];`.

If you need only the value, you can use:

`varOptions.match(/dialogHeight:(\w+)/)[1];`.

As founddrama suggested, if `dialogHeight` is not a substring of `varOptions` the code will produce an error. Better way of doing the above thing is:

```
var match = varOptions.match(/dialogHeight:(\w+)/);
if (match && match.length >= 1) {
    console.log("The value is: " + match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Though it's worth noting here that if `varOptions` does *not* contain `dialogHeight` then `match` will return `null` and trying optimistically to retrieve the indexed value of the match will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand your problem. YOU fill the varOptions, don't you? Just create new variable for each option and re-use them all you want.

So something like

```
var dialogHeight = 580;
var dialogWidth = 700;
var center = 'yes';
var scroll = 'no';

var options = 'dialogHeight:'+ dialogHeight +'px;dialogWidth:'+ dialogWidth '+x;center='+ center +';scroll='+ scroll;
var retval = window.showModalDialog(dialog, varArgIn, options);
alert('Reusing dialog height vairable here:'+ dialogHeight);
```

If you want to get dialogHeight out from the string you gave, you could do the following:

```
var input = 'dialogHeight:580px;dialogWidth:700px;center=yes;scroll=no';
var dialogHeight = input.match(/(?!dialogHeight:)[0-9]*(?=p)/ ,input);
alert(dialogHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E67RF/ <- working fiddle with this code

Comment: No, I'm overwriting the normal functionality of the showModalDialog function *don't ask why ;-)* - `function showModalDialogNEW(dialog, varArgIn, varOptions){ // jquery modal, with re-use of the dialogWith argument of the parameter`

Comment: I improved my answer, see if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions in following way:

```
var s= 'dialogHeight:580px;dialogWidth:700px;center=yes;scroll=no';
alert(s.match(/dialogHeight:[\w]+\;/)[0].match(/:[\w]+;/)[0].replace(':',''));
```

Comment: Why you do all these strange things when you can extract the value with the regex?

Comment: Because goal for question is to extract value of attribute, not attribute and value together...

Comment: `varOptions.match(/dialogHeight:(\d+px)/)[1];` extracts only the value without chaining all these functions together. The regex above simply uses regular expression groups. Here's a reference http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: ok you are right, but when value of attribute is do not contain only digits?

Comment: Yes it may contains `auto` too, so your use of `\w` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are liable to need any of the other values it will be useful to have a function that converts the string of options into a dictionary-style object.

```
function getOptions(s) {
  var r = {}, kv;
  s = s.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    kv = s[i].split(s[i].indexOf(':') > -1 ? ':' : '=');
    r[kv[0]] = kv[1];
  }
  return r;
}
var opts = 'dialogHeight:580px;dialogWidth:700px;center=yes;scroll=no';
var optsObj = getOptions(opts);
console.log(optsObj.dialogHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't already have the values, as in @Henrik Peinar's answer, you can parse the value from the string, (as long as it follows the conventions in your example).

Here are a couple ways you could do it:

1) Format the string to JSON notation, convert to object, access values

```
var objOptions = JSON.parse("{" + varOptions.replace(/;/g,",").replace(/=/g,":").replace(/(\w+)/g,'"$1"') + "}");

console.log(objOptions.dialogHeight);
```

2) Parse out only the value you're looking for using RegEx (my example is prone to errors, so I would do it a bit differently in production.  This is just a quick example.)

```
varOptions.match(/dialogHeight:(\w+);/)[1]
```

3) Use `split` to get an array of the name-value pairs, then loop and split those results, testing the 'name' piece until you find the one you want.  (I'm running out of time, so I've left off this example)

Answer (score 0):

```
var parseDialogOptions = function() {
  var optionDivider = /\s*;\s*/
    , valueDivider = /\s*[:=]\s*/
    , whiteSpace = /^\s+|\s+$/g

  return function(optionString) {
    var options = optionString.split(optionDivider)
      , obj = {}
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
      var parts = options[i].split(valueDivider)
      if (parts.length == 2) {
        obj[parts[0].replace(whiteSpace, '')] = parts[1].replace(whiteSpace, '')
      }
    }
    return obj
  }
}()
```

Usage:

```
>>> parseDialogOptions('dialogHeight:580px;dialogWidth : 700px; center=yes ; scroll=no ; ')
Object { dialogHeight="580px", dialogWidth="700px", center="yes", scroll="no" }
```